# Android database from webservice

Tags: java, php, android, database, web-services

I'm wondering the easiest way to go about this. I've used retro fit for java before to post and get from endpoints in web service my friend wrote in python.. However I've never wrote server side stuff.  I have phpmyadmin running on a vitural server... Havnt used it yet however. I just need people to be able to like or dislike a poem on my database. I know how to create the database...  What is the best way for me to do this? I've looked this up on Google with so many results but not sure where to start!

Comment: That's a big question. Maybe you want to go through a php tutorial to make the database on the server.

Comment: OK Leo I'll look into that! Thanks for your response.

Comment: A big question. Matt Raible has turned it into a full time obsession. If your interested in JVM frameworks his research makes good reading, http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/devoxx_france_a_great_conference. In summary the most popular frameworks for JVM are Spring MVC, Play and Grails with a lot of debate on which is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the easiest way to go about a restful service. Google app engine! You can easily create endpoints and add objects like a breeze!